# Loading image bounding boxes outputs equal size error

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to create a PyTorch dataloader for my dataset. Each image has a certain number of cars and a bounding box for each of them, not all images have the same amount of bounding boxes.

You probably wont be able to run it, but here is some info.
This is my data loader

```
class AGR_Dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, annotations_root, img_root, transform=None):
        """
        Arguments:
            annotations_root (string): Path to the csv file with annotations.
            img_root (string): Directory with all the images.
            transform (callable, optional): Optional transform to be applied
                on a sample.
        """
        self.annotations_root = annotations_root
        self.img_root = img_root
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.annotations_root)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # idx may be the index or image name, I think image naem
        if torch.is_tensor(idx):
            idx = idx.tolist()
        
        idx_name = os.listdir(self.img_root)[idx]
        # print(idx_name)
        
        img_name = os.path.join(self.img_root, idx_name)
        annotation_data = os.path.join(self.annotations_root, f"{idx_name.removesuffix('.jpg')}.txt")
        # print(img_name, annotation_data)

        image = io.imread(img_name)

        with open(annotation_data, 'r') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            img_data = []
            img_labels = []
            for line in lines:
                line = line.split(',')
                line = [i.strip() for i in line]
                line = [float(num) for num in line[0].split()]
                img_labels.append(int(line[0]))
                img_data.append(line[1:])

        boxes = tv_tensors.BoundingBoxes(img_data, format='CXCYWH', canvas_size=(image.shape[0], image.shape[1]))

        # sample = {'image': image, 'bbox': boxes, 'labels': img_labels}
        sample = {'image': image, 'bbox': boxes}

        if self.transform:
            sample = self.transform(sample)

        print(sample['image'].shape)
        print(sample['bbox'].shape)
        # print(sample['labels'].shape)
        return sample
```

I run my transforms and create the dataloader

```
data_transform = v2.Compose([
    v2.ToImage(),
    # v2.Resize(680),
    v2.RandomResizedCrop(size=(680, 680), antialias=True),
    # v2.ToDtype(torch.float32, scale=True),
    v2.ToTensor()
])

transformed_dataset = AGR_Dataset(f'{annotations_path}/test/', 
                        f'{img_path}/test/',
                        transform=data_transform)

dataloader = DataLoader(transformed_dataset, batch_size=2,
                        shuffle=False, num_workers=0)
```

Then I am trying to iterate through it with this, and eventually view and image with the bounding boxes.

```
for i, sample in enumerate(dataloader):
    print(i, sample)
    print(i, sample['image'].size(), sample['bbox'].size())

    if i == 4:
        break
```

With a batch size of 1, it runs properly, with a batch size of 2, I get this error

```
torch.Size([3, 680, 680])
torch.Size([12, 4])

torch.Size([3, 680, 680])
torch.Size([259, 4])

RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [12, 4] at entry 0 and [259, 4] at entry 1
```

1. I believe it is due to the number of bounding boxes not being equal, but how do I overcome this?
2. Do I need the ToTensor in my transforms? I am starting to think I don't as v2 uses ToImage(), and ToTensor is becoming depreciated.

Any other comments or help would be appreciated.
I am not sure how to create a working example, I will continue to try.

**What I have tried**
I have tried not loading the bounding boxes in as tensors, by commenting the `tv_tensors.BoundingBoxes` line in the dataloader, but then for some reason my resize doesnt work properly.

I just tried splitting bboxes and images like this in the dataloader

```
sample = image
    target = {'bbox': boxes, 'labels': img_labels}
```

No luck with that

Comment: Everybody, this is solved! I was looking for days to no avail, but then after I posted this I found the answer here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/dataloader-collate-fn-throws-runtimeerror-stack-expects-each-tensor-to-be-equal-size-in-response-to-variable-number-of-bounding-boxes/117952

A collate_fn was added to the dataloader, and just like that it works!

Comment: But this raises another question. If I am converting it to a tuple, and it was a tensor, is it still going to be loaded on my gpu?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be kind enough and self-answer your question properly by posting an answer below. Notice that answers should not be link-only - you should include the essential parts here; afterwards, you could possibly open a new question (and linking here if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to the problem.

In the dataloader, the `collate_fn` needs to be set to the collate_fn in the utils package that torchvision has!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).